# How can I assign a pointer to an array [ ] in c?

Tags: c, pointers

How can I assign a pointer to an array in c?
As in this example, I want to some.x has values stored in vals

```
typedef struct s
{
    int x[];
}s;

int main()
{   
    int* vals = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vals[i] = i + 10;

    s some;
    //some.x = vals?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign anything to an array.

Comment: take a look here: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @yano thanks - very interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to allocate a structure with a flexible array member, and not *assign* a pointer to an array (which as others have stated - you can't do that)

To use a flexible array member, you need to allocate the *structure* plus an amount of memory for the array.

```
typedef struct s
{
    int x[];
}s;

int main()
{   
    s *some = malloc( sizeof( *some ) + ( 10 * sizeof( int ) ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        some->x[i] = i + 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can not leave the `sizeof( struct ... )` out of the allocation - the structure's presence is not guaranteed to be zero, even when the flexible array member is the only field in the structure.

As @chux noted in the comments, this would be more consistent with using variables instead of types as `sizeof()` arguments:

```
    s *some = malloc( sizeof( *some ) + ( 10 * sizeof( some->x[0] ) ) );
```

Comment: For consistency of `sizeof(variable)` vs. `sizeof (type)`, could use `malloc( sizeof  *some +  10*sizeof some->x[0] );`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want. It is outside of the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Arrays do decay into pointers, but not the other way round. You cannot assign to an array.

So use *systematically* pointers.

And your code cannot have any sense: think of the `sizeof` involved data!

Read about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You'll use pointers to a  `struct` containing them.

Comment: hm, I just want to create the `_SCATTER_GATHER_LIST` structure from MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_scatter_gather_list and I don't know how to assign elements to `SCATTER_GATHER_ELEMENT Elements[];` field

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not pointers, thats all.